# TDMS file read data in python

Tags: python, readlines, read-data

During the project, I had to deal with a TDMS file.
I'm asking because the file could not be read immediately.

My Goal: Perform analysis by converting TDMS file into DataFrame format

**First attempt**,
-Perform TdmsFile open using npTdms package.
-Converts to read_data() to execute pd.DataFrame command.

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile, TdmsWriter, ChannelObject, GroupObject
filenameS = "ex.tdms"
tdms_file = TdmsFile(filenameS)

[enter image description here][1]
```

So I succeeded in loading using TdmsFile.open() command.

But I tried read_data() on the **second attempt** and checked the error.

```
csv_merge = pd.DataFrame()
for i in tdms_file.group_channels('Analog Data'):
temp = i.read_data()
csv_merge = pd.concat([csv_merge, pd.DataFrame({i.channel: temp})], axis=1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj0Oc.png)

**Last attempt**,

```
tdms_file = TdmsFile.open(filenameS)
df = tdms_file.as_dataframe()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5mxI.png)

Comment: can you post link to you tdms file?

Comment: Sent a Google Drive link, is it downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go =^..^=

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile
import pandas as pd

# load file
tdms_file = TdmsFile('20200609_130131.69.tdms')
# show groups
groups_data = tdms_file.groups()
print(groups_data)
# show channels
channels_data = tdms_file['group name'].channels()
print(channels_data)
# show data in channel
selected_data = tdms_file['group name']['channel name']
print(selected_data.data)

# load into df
df = pd.DataFrame(data=selected_data.data)
```

df output:

```
0  0.000000
1  0.111111
2  0.222222
3  0.333333
4  0.444444
5  0.555556
6  0.666667
7  0.777778
8  0.888889
9  1.000000
```

Comment: I just opened the script and an error occurred. I put an error code in the answer. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Okgukui i don't know what group names and channels are inside file, i just use default.

Comment: @Okgukui will by nice if you can accept my answer and give vote up for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know..

[image]

so, I did it using the TdmsFile.open() command. Then an error occurred
[image]

Comment: use read_data()